# Invoke-RestMethod : The operation has timed out

Tags: http, powershell

I have a script that deletes resources and creates new ones.  Every now and then it times out and I can't figure out why.  It seems to happen when I run the script multiple times, but I couldn't get a definite pattern.  I found that my server hasn't picked up the message yet since there's no logging for the request yet.

```
$old_values = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get

foreach($old_value in $old_values.result) {
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri&key=$old_value.id" -Method Delete
}

$new_value = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$uri" -Body "{}" -ContentType application/json -Method Post
```

Interesting note, I get occasional timeouts when I run the Invoke-RestMethod calls directly from powershell.  I also ran them with Fiddler and never got timeouts.

[Edit] I've been checking the connections with netstat.  While the commands are hanging, they're listed as ESTABLISHED.  But I keep seeing TIME_WAIT connections listed to my server.  Is there a chance my connections aren't getting closed?

Comment: Have you seen this? Might it be related? http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/836732/tcp-connection-hanging-in-close-wait-when-using-invoke-restmethod-with-put-or-delete

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link David Brabant posted above contains this workaround that solved the problem for me:

```
$r = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri `
    -Method 'POST' `
    -ContentType 'application/json' `
    -Body '{}' `
    ).Content | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Comment: This bug is fixed in Powershell 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bring up old topic. We are using Win 7 now and PowerShell version 3.0
We encountered the same problem with POST method. When we POST the same JSON the 3rd time, powershell window will hang. After close and reopen it will work.

To get around it, simple add 2 lines at the end of POST:

```
$ServicePoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint('<URL>')
$ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("")
```

refer: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29863.powershell-rest-api-invoke-restmethod-gotcha.aspx

Comment: Super old question and answer, but I just had to use this. Our TFS build was calling an API in PowerShell and it started timing out after the web server hosting the API was upgraded to Windows 2016. I added your first line right before my Invoke-RestMethod and the other line after.

Answer (score 0):

I found Allanrbo's answer to still timeout after 3 or 4 runs.

I did the following instead:

```
powershell "(Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Delete' -Uri '$uri').Content"
```